# $n,a\in \mathbb Z,n\geq1,$ prove that $x^3+x+1\nmid x^n+a$

Tags: polynomials, roots

$n,a\in \mathbb Z,n\geq1,$ prove that $x^3+x+1\nmid x^n+a.$ In other word, they have no common roots.

My idea: Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the roots of $x^3+x+1=0,$ we need to prove that $\dfrac{x_1}{x_2}$ is not a [root of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Comment: The first statement of non-divisibility is not equivalent to the polynomials not having any common roots.

Comment: @Ragib Zaman $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible, hence it's equivalent.

Comment: Fair point, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $x^3 + x + 1 \mid x^n + a$, any root of $x^3 + x + 1$ is a root of $x^n + a$.
Consider the real root.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We take your approach a little further. Since the ratios are roots of unity, the roots have equal norm. The norm of the product is $1$, so the roots have norm $1$.